# unable to find valid certification path to requested target even after successful certificate import

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

I have successfully imported the .pem certificates(2 certificates, one being intermediate)
i can see them with below command in trust store

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts
```

I am getting below error with my java client

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

When i try with openssl command

```
openssl s_client -connect ****:443 -showcerts
```

i am getting below error

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

however when i pass the combined certificate(combined pem file path) to openssl command(here path is not trust store path, the disk path for a copy of pem file)

```
openssl s_client -connect ***:443 -showcerts -CAfile combined.pem
```

i am getting below response

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

I am trying to understand if the issue is with my certificate import or server side certificate chaining?

any help is appreciated

Comment: To be clear, you imported the root and intermediate each to a different (and unique) alias? The default truststore is JRE/lib/security/cacerts -- is that the file you imported to? Do you have more than one JRE on your system? Are you sure your java client uses the default, i.e. it is not configured to use some other file and is not coded to use some other file or data source? (Is 'my' client one you write or maintain or just one you are running?) FWIW if the server is working correctly, _both_ OpenSSL and Java should need only the root not the intermediate(s), but many servers aren't correct.

Comment: hi @dave_thompson_085 1) i imported both root and intermediate certificates with diff alias 2) i have only one jre in my machine 3)my client uses the only one available default jre

Comment: my biggest concern is, if certificate is successfully imported to trust store, we dont need to pass the out side certificate path to openssl command right?

Comment: The cacerts file is the _default_ truststore for a JRE but that doesn't mean a particular client uses it -- that depends as I said on the configuration (specifically sysprops `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*`) AND the code, neither of which you have indicated. Java and OpenSSL use differerent and separate truststores -- putting a cert (or two) in a Java truststore has no effect on OpenSSL, and putting it (them) in an OpenSSL truststore has no effect on Java.